# Progaurd and R8 shrink ofuscate the code and unable to make a build

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Errors:

```
Missing class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM (referenced from: com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM com.amazon.A3L.messaging.ADM.ADMMessagingHelper.admInstance and 7 other contexts)

Missing class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory (referenced from: long org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout.cpuTime(java.lang.Thread) and 1 other context)

Missing class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean (referenced from: void org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug.\<init\>(org.junit.rules.TestRule))

Missing class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean (referenced from: long org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout.cpuTime(java.lang.Thread))
```

Code:

```
# Keep specific classes or packages from larger libraries

# Keep required Android framework classes

-keep class org.matomo.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.** { *; }
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.exoplayer2.** { *; }
-keep class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.** { *; }
-keep class com.karumi.dexter.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.zxing.** { *; }
-keep class com.pallycon.** { *; }
-keep class org.matomo.sdk.** { *; }


-keep class android.content.** { *; }
-keep class android.view.** { *; }
-keep class android.os.Bundle { *; }
-keep class android.os.Parcelable { *; }
-keep class android.util.Log { *; }
-keep class android.os.StrictMode { *; }

-keep class android.app.Application
-keep class android.app.Activity
-keep class android.app.Service
-keep class android.app.BroadcastOptions
-keep class android.app.AppComponentFactory
-keep class android.app.Notification


-keep class com.prasarbharati.bharat.ott.** { *; }


-dontwarn com.google.common.util.**
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture.**
-dontwarn androidx.work.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
#retrofit
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclassmembers class **.R$layout {
    public static <fields>;
}


# XML layout rules
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
     public <init>(android.content.Context);
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
     public void set*(...);
}

# Dagger Hilt
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-keep class dagger.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.dagger.** { *; }
-keep class dagger.hilt.** { *; }

# Avoid obfuscating native method names
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

#-keep class com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM { *; }
#-keep class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory { *; }
#-keep class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean { *; }
#-keep class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean { *; }


-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLParameters
```

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        isShrinkResources = true
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }

    debug {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        isShrinkResources = true
        proguardFiles (getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error while  isMinifyEnabled = true
        isShrinkResources = true

how to implement progaurd successfullly

Comment: The subject should describe the technical issue. Please edit it.

Comment: You forgot to describe when those errors appear and what happens afterwards. Does the build process stops or do you get an APK in the end? That libraries contain references to non-existent glasses is not so unusual e.g. if it supports Android and J2SE in one library.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix errors connected with proguard you need to check official repositories and/or docs for them and find a section describing the proguard rules.

For example, I suppose that the error from your post is connected with *Amazon Device Messaging* and [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/adm/set-up.html#configuring-proguard) docs with rules for proguard.

Comment: After adding  ..   -libraryjars libs    .... this line I am getting new error now

Unexpected input type. Only archive types are supported, e.g., .jar, .zip, etc.